# How to load output of a query to .csv file in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario as to load output of a query to load to a .csv file using ADF.

How can we achieve this? File should be placed in a blob container.

Comment: Hey, where are you executing your query? Is it sql server or Azure database etc

Comment: @Nandan , Thing is that there are tables in Hive. I want to run validations on those tables. for example : If a table contains duplicates. If it is , then I want to load all those duplicate values to a file and send this as attachment to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Copy activity in Azure data factory wherein Hive can be your source and sink can be Azure blob storage.

MSFT Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-hive?tabs=data-factory